# how to make logos like these? any tutorial online?

Tags: vector, logo

I am a student of graphics, and was looking for some inspirational logos and came across these, they look beautiful and I tried to make one myself but failed. How can anyone make such perfect logos? with exact same width and height exact distance.
What are these logos called? Is there any tutorial online? Can someone please help me in learning how to make these types of logos? Do i need some kind of illustrator script or action for this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that they all are basically the same method, _except_ the last one, which is a different technique altogether.

Answer (score 2):

They draw them.

That's how most all 'high quality' logos are done. Someone takes the time to craft them by hand.

A tutorial can't really help with basic design concepts like balance, color, weight, contrast, movement, etc. That's just something that will come with practice and experience.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called [Processing](http://processing.org/) that is perfect for some of these; in particular, that umbrella. You could import the umbrella, generate a random point, test to see if the point is inside the umbrella, and if it is, use the point to draw a circle of a random radius. You could even control the density of the circles from left to right. Lullaby might have started as something generated as well.

However, I'd confidently say that some of these were almost certainly arranged by hand (The H and the Social Dog being the most obvious to my eye), and I'd be surprised if all of them weren't touched by a human at some point. Even if the umbrella was generated programmatically, it was probably touched by a human at some point to refine. Truly random art tends to look a lot more erratic than the very-well refined logos you're showing us.

Illustrator can be scripted to do some of this stuff, but it's not really built with scripting in mind. Definitely give Processing a look if you're interested in generative art.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by breaking down the process. 
Each one is creating a larger shape from smaller shapes.

First, create the larger shape.

Create a a few varying smaller shapes (maybe 2-3).
Try creating using symbols (symbol will come in handy because you can edit the symbol and it would effect all if you want to change) or as the above comment link states the scatter brush.

Duplicate and arrange the smaller shapes into the larger shape, 
or if using the scatter brush method, expand the strokes and move them around to your desired effect.

Try experimenting with grouping the smaller shapes to one layer and creating a mask with the large shape. then adding more outside the mask to give it that breakout effect.